# How can multiple commands be stored and executed using a bash array

Tags: bash

Given the following snippet:

```
command0=( docker exec -it container_name )
command1=( ls -l )
command2=( echo foo )
#commands1and2=?
commands=( "${command0[@]}" "${commands1and2[@]}" )
"${commands[@]}"
```

When commands1and2 is:

```
commands1and2=( "${command1[@]}" "&&" "${command2[@]}" )
```

...the result is an error:

```
ls: &&: No such file or directory
ls: echo: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, `&&, echo, foo` get interpreted as arguments to `ls -l`.

When commands1and2 is:

```
commands1and2=( echo "$("${command1[@]}" && "${command2[@]}")" )
```

...the result is successful.

Is there a way to avoid using command substitution `$("${command1[@]}" && "${command2[@]}")` and backticks?

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be _one_ array?

Comment: _In general_, one array should be used per command. If you want to store a list of commands... have you considered a function instead?

Comment: Note that it's possible to iterate over defined variables -- you can retrieve the list of variables defined with names that start with `command`, f/e, and separately execute each in turn.

Comment: Maybe a function would serve just right. Can you provide the answer as an example? Do you mean in your third comment that I should delimit the command lines using a list of possible command binary/script names they can start with during the iterations and call them after concatenating the relevant arguments?

Comment: ...so, what I meant by the third comment: Let's say that you have `CommandA_001=( docker exec -it container_name )` and `CommandA_002=( ls -l )`. You can write code that iterates over `"${!CommandA_@}"`, thereby finds both those variables, and executes them in turn.

Comment: The reason I'm storing them in one array is because I have different smaller functions which can be combined in many ways and need to construct the final function when testing the value of the first positional argument to the script.

Comment: ...as for a function: `command1and2() { docker exec -it container_name && ls -l; }` is a really simple example. It can be exported to the environment with `export -f command1and2` (if you need it to be accessible to subprocesses), or run by just invoking `command1and2`.

Comment: ...or, `command1and2() { command1 && command2; }`, if you defined `command1` and `command2` as functions themselves. BTW, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 discusses functions as one of the possible solutions to storing commands for reuse (though it's principally focused on people whose first response is to try to store those commands in a string, so parts of it teach the array approach you're already using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, and not something I would actually recommend doing, but as a working implementation that avoids introducing security flaws:

```
printf -v command1_str '%q ' "${command1[@]}"
printf -v command2_str '%q ' "${command2[@]}"
commands1and2=( "bash" "-c" "${command1_str} && ${command2_str}" )
```

However -- in general, code should be stored in functions, *especially* code that goes beyond simple commands. (One can also iterate over the list of defined arrays whose name starts with a prefix, and execute each as a simple command in turn).

Comment: Seems like functions is what I'm looking for. Accepting your answer which quotes the commands using `printf` because it does exactly what was being asked in the question.